# Why Google Maps knows exact geolocation, but when I use Google map API Geolocation it is not so accurate?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Why Google Maps knows exact geolocation, but when I use Google map API Geolocation it is not so accurate? 
I use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().
It gives the right country, but not the city and address.
I expect it work accurately like in google maps.  What do I miss?

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is a browser function, it doesn't know what Google Maps knows about you (and isn't Google Maps API Geolocation).  Is this on a computer or a mobile device?

Comment: I see. It is on the computer. Do Google maps have API for Geolocation?

Comment: The examples in their documentation that I could find all use the HTML5 `navigator.geolocation`

Comment: The Geolocation API uses WiFi access points and cell tower data to locate you, which is why it is less accurate than the HTML5 geolocation in your phone. This is by design. If you have the ability to use HTML5 geolocation and need highest accuracy, then use that. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#troubleshooting

Comment: But (as per @ecg8) there is a [Geolocation web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro)

Comment: Thank you, it is useful